# log4j logging levels changing automatically

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using log4j for logging. Here is my log4j.properties

```
log = C:/Mahiz/Temp/UAT/Logs
log4j.rootLogger = INFO,FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n

log4j.appender.S = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.S.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.S.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n
```

I set the root Logger as INFO. For the first time (after tomcat restarts) the info and above level messages are getting logged properly. From the second time on wards the level getting changed to ERROR. I retrieved the level using below code

```
System.out.println(logger.getRootLogger().getLevel().toString());
```

What it the problem in my code?

Comment: Is it set programmatically somewhere?

Comment: Yes Fildor, you are right. Some of the libaries I used changing the log levels. But not resetting back. Now I am setting after calling the method of that class. Thanks.